# How to make payment to two different Bank Accounts at a time in drupal 7

Tags: commerce

In Drupal 7, If any user purchases the product then the commission of that product should deposit into "website owner account" and the remaining amount should deposit into the "Product Company Account". Which module is best suitable for this flow. (i.e., Drupal E-commerce or Ubecart or any other suggesions...). Please suggest ASAP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what research have you done? ... i imagine with any module you can add an additional submit handler to any purchase and submit payment to different locations ...

Comment: There is no such payment gateway which you can integrate with your system without going to their website to make payments. Then how you go to 2 diff websites in same time ?